# C++ constructor signature autocompletion trips over namespace in XCode

Tags: xcode, xcode8

In XCode 8.1, when working on a C++ project, I just can't get any constructor signature autocompletion when they are "obstructed" by a namespace. Which is incredibly annoying because namespaces are extremely useful and extensively used in both my code and the code my software depends on.

Let me explain in two images.

[Accessing through the `std` namespace.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmHQv.png)

[Spilling the entire `std`namespace into the source with `using namespace`.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3TTo.png)

My question is basically... *What?*

Comment: My current workaround is temporarily bring in only certain elements of the namespace and then remove them once I decide on a signature. [Like so.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZM136.png)